# Setting flash as3 volume level before sound starts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, volume

I've read that a volume control in flash actionscript 3 can't be used without getting an error unless the sound has started.

In my case, I've a bunch of buttons that trigger sounds while being pushed, the sound stops upon mouse_up. Therefore a volume control won't work since there's no way to use it during sounds since the mouse is busy over a button.
Does it mean it's not possible to give the user any volume control inside flash in this case?

Comment: By volume control do you mean a standard flash component slider?

Comment: well, any volume control that can adjust the volume, whichever it is.

Comment: did you find a solution? please either accept an answer, or post your own answer (and upvote anything that was useful in getting there)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where "have you read" but that's not true, you should create your SoundTransform object and set the volume property. Then each time you play a sound assign the SoundTransform to the SoundChannel object.

```
channel1 = mySound.play();
channel1.soundTransform = volumeAdjust;
```

Comment: it was in an online tutorial, then i thought it made sense since i couldn't think of a flash player online which enables volume adjustment prior to hitting the play-button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the volume controls to set a volume variable in your code, and use that variable for setting the volume when playing the sounds.

For setting the volume for all sounds, use SoundMixer class. Initialize it before any interaction like this:

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1); //volume is set to maximum
```

In your event listeners for volume controls, modify the volume property of SoundMixer.soundTranform accordingly to your new value.

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform.volume = newVolumeValue;
```

Make sure your newVolumeValue is between 0 and 1.
Alternatively if you have a large number of sounds to manage, you could use a sound manager library like [SoundAS](https://github.com/treefortress/SoundAS). If you use that, you would have a helpful method to set the master volume: SoundAS.setMasterVolume(value)

Comment: "volume controls"? This is such a vague answer talking about things that don't even exist in Actionscript. There is a SoundTransfom class that is meant to control volume and other things for sounds so "volume controls" is falling very short.

Comment: Well, the question talks about volume controls which I assume are movie clips that can be used to lower or up the volume, or a slider. The question is pretty vague in itself.

Comment: even in that case your answer does not provide anything new or usable to solve the issue. You are merely stating what the user already know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a flashPro slider control as a master volume control (on the timeline with a instance name of `slider` and a min of 0 and a max of 100).  You could do the following:

```
import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

var slider:Slider;
var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(slider.value / 100); //set it right now to whatever the slider is
SoundMixer.soundTransform = st;

slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,function(e){
    st.volume = slider.value / 100;
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = st; //SoundMixer is global volume, if you want volume specific to each sound, go with the answer from @SharpEdge
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i will look closer into SoundTransform. Wondering though why it needs to be passed 'slider.value / 100' twice, is it necessary? Also, does flash understand that the global volume should apply to the buttons as long as they're all on the same time line? No

Comment: Global is global, it will affect every sound that comes out of flash player regardless of any other factor.  The reason you see it twice, is once is the initial value (which will be whatever you've set the slider default to), the second is in the event handler for whenever the slider value changes.

Comment: Thanks. ignore the 'No' at the end, was mistake, edits disabled